# Using ORDER BY and UNION ALL in the same SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why is this not giving the expected results?

```
SELECT top 1 CITY, LEN(CITY) FROM STATION ORDER BY LEN (city) desc
union all 
SELECT top 1 CITY, LEN(CITY) FROM STATION ORDER BY LEN (city) asc;
```

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53788111/edit) into your question what exactly your're expecting this statement to return? Without knowing what you're looking for, it's going to be hard for anyone to help you out.

Comment: Please post sample data and expected results.

Comment: What is your expected result???

Answer (score 1):

Each of your ordered queries will need to be represented as a subquery, as `union` cannot follow `order by`, hence:

```
select a.* from (select top 1 city, len(city) from station order by len(city) desc) a
union all 
select b.* from (select top 1 city, len(city) from station order by len(city)) b
```

Comment: Looks like this question is a sql task from HackerRank, there are a lot of "select something from a STATION table" tasks =) And this answer is definitely acceptable.